# Drawer onClose not working when onClick in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using template from HorizonUI with ChakraUI and ReactJS, i just add Drawer when click Navbar component, i call Links component in Drawer body, Drawer closing if click close button and outside Drawer but cant close if click Links Component

This the Links component on Drawer

```
<Links routes={routes} onClick={onClose}/>
```

This Navbar.js

```
import Links from "components/sidebar/components/Links";
export default function AdminNavbar(props) {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
    const { secondary, brandText } = props;
    let mainText = useColorModeValue('navy.700', 'white');
    let navbarPosition = 'fixed';
    let navbarFilter = 'none';
    let navbarBackdrop = 'blur(20px)';
    let navbarShadow = 'none';
    let navbarBg = useColorModeValue('rgba(244, 247, 254, 0.2)', 'rgba(11,20,55,0.5)');
    let navbarBorder = 'transparent';
    let secondaryMargin = '0px';
    let gap = '0px';
    return (
        <Box
            position={navbarPosition}
            boxShadow={navbarShadow}
            bg={navbarBg}
            borderColor={navbarBorder}
            filter={navbarFilter}
            backdropFilter={navbarBackdrop}
            backgroundPosition='center'
            backgroundSize='cover'
            borderRadius='16px'
            alignItems={{ xl: 'center' }}
            display={secondary ? 'block' : 'flex'}
            minH='50px'
            justifyContent={{ xl: 'center' }}
            lineHeight='25.6px'
            mx='auto'
            mt={secondaryMargin}
            top={{ base: '12px', md: '16px', lg: '20px', xl: '20px' }}
            right={{ base: '500px' }}
            left={{ base: '500px' }}
            
            onClick={onOpen}
            >
            <Flex
                alignItems={{ xl: 'center' }}
                mb={gap}
            >
                <Box>
                    <Text color={mainText}
                        
                        href='#'
                        bg='inherit'
                        borderRadius='inherit'
                        fontWeight='bold'
                        fontSize='34px'
                        _hover={{ color: { mainText } }}
                        _active={{
                            bg: 'inherit',
                            transform: 'none',
                            borderColor: 'transparent'
                        }}
                        _focus={{
                            boxShadow: 'none'
                        }}
                        style={{ userSelect: "none" }}>
                            {brandText}
                        </Text>
                </Box>
            </Flex>
            <Drawer placement="top" isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} size='xs' blockScrollOnMount={false}>
                <DrawerOverlay />
                <DrawerContent 
                boxShadow={navbarShadow}
                bg={navbarBg}
                borderColor={navbarBorder}
                filter={navbarFilter}
                backdropFilter={navbarBackdrop}
                backgroundPosition='center'
                backgroundSize='cover'
                borderRadius='16px'
                alignItems={{ xl: 'center' }}
                justifyContent={{ xl: 'center' }}
                lineHeight='25.6px'
                mx='auto'
                >
                <DrawerCloseButton />
                <DrawerHeader
                    color={mainText}
                    href='#'
                    fontWeight='bold'
                    fontSize='40px'
                    style={{ userSelect: "none" }}
                    onClick={onClose}>
                        Inventory SCM
                </DrawerHeader>
                <DrawerBody>
                    <Links routes={routes} onClick={onClose}/>
                </DrawerBody>
                </DrawerContent>
            </Drawer>
        </Box>      
    );
}
```

and this component Links.js

```
export function SidebarLinks(props) {
  let location = useLocation();
  let activeColor = useColorModeValue("gray.700", "white");
  let inactiveColor = useColorModeValue(
    "secondaryGray.600",
    "secondaryGray.600"
  );
  let activeIcon = useColorModeValue("brand.500", "white");
  let textColor = useColorModeValue("secondaryGray.500", "white");
  let brandColor = useColorModeValue("brand.500", "brand.400");
  const { routes } = props;
  const activeRoute = (routeName) => {
    return location.pathname.includes(routeName);
  };
  const createLinks = (routes) => {
    return routes.map((route, index) => {
      if (route.category) {
        return (
          <>
            <Text
              fontSize={"md"}
              color={activeColor}
              fontWeight='bold'
              mx='auto'
              ps={{
                sm: "10px",
                xl: "16px",
              }}
              pt='18px'
              pb='12px'
              key={index}>
              {route.name}
            </Text>
            {createLinks(route.items)}
          </>
        );
      } else if (
        route.layout === "/admin" ||
        route.layout === "/auth" ||
        route.layout === "/rtl"
      ) {
        return (
          <NavLink key={index} to={route.layout + route.path}>
            {route.icon ? (
              <Box>
                <HStack
                  spacing={
                    activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase()) ? "22px" : "26px"
                  }
                  py='5px'
                  ps='10px'>
                  <Flex w='100%' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center'>
                    <Box
                      color={
                        activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase())
                          ? activeIcon
                          : textColor
                      }
                      me='18px'>
                      {route.icon}
                    </Box>
                    <Text
                      me='auto'
                      color={
                        activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase())
                          ? activeColor
                          : textColor
                      }
                      fontWeight={
                        activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase())
                          ? "bold"
                          : "normal"
                      }>
                      {route.name}
                    </Text>
                  </Flex>
                  <Box
                    h='36px'
                    w='4px'
                    bg={
                      activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase())
                        ? brandColor
                        : "transparent"
                    }
                    borderRadius='5px'
                  />
                </HStack>
              </Box>
            ) : (
              <Box>
                <HStack
                  spacing={
                    activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase()) ? "22px" : "26px"
                  }
                  py='5px'
                  ps='10px'>
                  <Text
                    me='auto'
                    color={
                      activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase())
                        ? activeColor
                        : inactiveColor
                    }
                    fontWeight={
                      activeRoute(route.path.toLowerCase()) ? "bold" : "normal"
                    }>
                    {route.name}
                  </Text>
                  <Box h='36px' w='4px' bg='brand.400' borderRadius='5px' />
                </HStack>
              </Box>
            )}
          </NavLink>
        );
      }
    });
  };
  return createLinks(routes);
}
export default SidebarLinks;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think your `Link.js` isn't calling the `onClick` method at all. Please define the same, it will start working.

Just an example:

```
// ...

const createLinks = (routes) => {
  const { onClick } = props; // Receive the onClick method from the parent component

  return routes.map((route, index) => {
    // ...

    return (
      <NavLink
        key={index}
        to={route.layout + route.path}
        onClick={() => {
          // Invoke the onClick method and pass the route object or any other data you need
          onClick(route);
        }}
      >
        {route.icon ? (
          // ...
        ) : (
          // ...
        )}
      </NavLink>
    );
  });
};

// ...

export function SidebarLinks(props) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i already do it, and still not close when onClick

Comment: Actually it depends on which component is being rendered. I can see you have a lot of different types of components. You have to define onClick for each component you're returning. 